# CQ5 Reverse Replication

Tags: aem

If there are 3-4 publish environments. In reverse replication, if user has added a comment in any publish environment say Publish1, will it be reflecting in all other publish environments? Or first it will come to the author and then after approval it will reflect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, as you say, the content will first come to the Author instance. The process will be:

1. User posts comment in Publish1
2. Comment goes into Publish1 outbox
3. Author polls all Publish instances to see if new comments are present
4. Author retrieves new comment from Publish1 and puts it in moderation queue.
5. When activated, replication agents on Author push content to Publish 1–6.

As far as I remember, the comment isn't truly even published on the *Publish1* environment until it goes through this process above, though the user who posted the comment will be able to see it from his session data. If you cleared the session or accessed Publish1 directly through another browser for instance, you wouldn't see the comment.

According to the [Adobe documentation](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/deploying/replication.html#Replicating%20from%20Publish%20to%20Author) (my emphasis):

> Features such as comments and forms, allow users to enter information
>   on a publish instance. For this a type of replication is needed to
>   **return this information to the author environment, from where it is
>   redistributed to other publish environments**. However, due to security
>   considerations, any traffic from the publish to the author environment
>   must be strictly controlled.
>
> This is known as reverse replication and functions using an agent in
>   the publish environment which references the author environment. This
>   agent places the input into an outbox. This outbox is matched with
>   replication listeners in the author environment. The listeners poll
>   the outboxes to collect any input made and then distribute it as
>   necessary. **This ensures that the author environment controls all
>   traffic.**

You should try it out — even without dedicated servers, you can check this by starting up a couple of copies of the Quickstart JAR on different port numbers & giving them multiple replication agents to test replication across them.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it way and went through the documentation. It was really helpful.Yes, it doesn't go to pub1 before the above mentioned steps. It goes to all the environments only after author.

once again, thanks for your response